# How do you get a javascript function to recognize html code returned by an ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I apologize ahead of time if this question has been addressed...I looked and did not see one. I am building a web app using flask. After successfully logging in the user is routed to index.html via the following code:

```
@blueprint.route('/index')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('home/index.html', segment='index')
```

My index.html includes an ajax request which builds and returns custom html such as:

```
<div class="card" style="max-width: 22rem;">
    <!-- Card content -->
    <div class="card-body pb-3">
        <!-- Title -->
        <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold">TailNumber</h4>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted d-flex justify-content-between">
            <p>AircraftType</p>
            <p>Operator</p>
        </h6>
        <div class="collapse-content">
            <div class="collapse" id="tail_number" style="">
                <table class="table table-borderless table-sm mb-0">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="font-weight-normal align-middle">Engine</td>
                        <td class="float-right font-weight-normal">
                            <p class="mb-1">2.5<span class="text-muted">IPS</span></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <hr class="">
            <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tail_number"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-pressed="false" aria-controls="tail_number">Show
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also include a javascript function designed to change the text of my "collapse" button from "Show" to "Hide" and back again as the content is expanded and collapsed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).text("Hide");
      } else {
        $(this).text("Show");
      }
    });
});
```

While the collapse feature of my html code works the text is not being updated. If I hard code the html instead of loading it via my ajax request then the button text changes as advertised. My assumption is that the javascript above is not being applied to the html returned by the ajax request but I am not sure how to verify this or, more importantly, correct it. My simplified ajax request is here:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        function update_fleet_view(){
            // create an ajax request
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

            req.open("GET", "/ajax", true);
            req.send();

            req.onload = function () {
                // update page with new fleet view
                var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                document.getElementById("fleet_view").innerHTML = data["fleet_view"];
                
                // timeout to run again after 1 minute
                setTimeout(update_fleet_view, 60000);
            }
        }
        // call the function to get it started
        update_fleet_view();
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: I'd read up on how to use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser). The response can then be treated as a document and you can append all or part of it to your original document.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption, the ajax-created elements are not assigned event listeners (because the ajax happens after document.ready).  One approach is Event Delegation, whereby you assign a single listener to some static (not ajax) element on the page that is a parent of the buttons.  Check https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Excellent! I'll look into both of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event delegation was exactly what I needed...thanks for the link [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535480/james).

I ended up with the following modifications to my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fleet_view").on("click", '[data-toggle="collapse"]', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
            $(this).text("Hide");
        } else {
            $(this).text("Show");
        }
    });
});
```

where `"fleet_view"` is the `"id"` that is referenced by my ajax script.

I attempted to leave the `$(this).toggleClass("active")` in the script however I could never get it to toggle. Rather than spending precious time tracking that issue down I decided to look at the `"collapsed"` field as the click event toggles that automatically. I also had to modify my button to add the `"collapsed"` class otherwise the button text would not update for the first round of clicks (see code below). The `"if/else"` statement seems backwards but I assure you it works as intended. Again, I can only assume that the `"collapsed"` class gets added or removed after this script executes.

```
<button class="btn collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tail_number"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-pressed="false" aria-controls="tail_number">Show
</button>
```